# Kubuntu: How to make dolphin show hidden files on bottom instead of on top

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

I am a power user and don't feel good, if I don't also always see the hidden files & folders.

But on top? This is so annoying. Can I set dolphin to show them on the bottom instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is indeed no way *yet* (Dolphin 5.28.0)

Beside sorting from Z-A, whcih feels totally awkward.

However there is a fork that implemented this, so I was not alone in this :-)

https://github.com/KDE/dolphin/compare/master...Zren:sortdotfileslast

Comment: still not possible in 20.04 ...

Answer (score 2):

Well, now finally it is possible in Dolphin to set in the sort options the setting "Hidden Files Last" and it is just doing what expected.

Tested with Dolphin Version 22.12, but it may be added already in previous versions.

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't available in Mint with Dolphin 22.04 in the repo, but I was looking in the wrong place, it's not in the Dolphin config window.
Menu -> Sort By -> Hidden Files Last.

Here's the PR, with screenshot, where it was merged into 21.08 or 21.12 (see comments): https://invent.kde.org/system/dolphin/-/merge_requests/252